# Windows Server Backup (2008) view more messages

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-backup

I'm using Windows Server Backup (on Windows 2008).  After I make a backup there's an entry in "Messages"; a log of success or failure.  However it limits itself to "Activity from last week".  How can I view more messages from the previous backups?  Or where are the messages / logs of the backups?

I know there is an event (event viewer->Applications and services logs->Microsoft->Backup->Operational) however it does not give me the size of backup and time started/ended (though I could do this manually); it's just not complete like the "Messages".

I have searched and google searched.  I didn't find the answer.

So, again, How can I view more messages from the previous backups?

Comment: Have you looked at the actual logs in %windir%\logs\windowsserverbackup?

Comment: TheCleaner: I have looked in that directory.  it looks like it has Restores, and failed backups, but not last nights (I did one last night).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any built-in way then.  MS support has its own internal tool for debugging it, but not the same.  You may try: http://www.magikmon.com/mksbackup/wbadmin.en.html or http://www.backupassist.com/index.html.  They both utilize Windows Backup but "enhance it"...but the 2nd one isn't free.

Other than that...if the event log entries under "Backup" in eventvwr are decent enough you could consider using an event viewer action to email you the event entries each time there is one and then just store those emails in a subfolder in your email using an auto-rule.  Best I can think of.